# What are some visual tools for the design of concurrent systems?

Tags: programming-languages, concurrency

I am looking for visual tools for the design, and optionally verifications, of concurrent systems.

PS:
There is no tag for visual-programming, I must have 150 reputation to create one, so please create one if you can.